# Finding $g'(t)$ of the function $ g (t) = \frac{s'(t) - 1}{t} $ using power series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> The function $ s $ defined as $ s(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{+ \infty} a_n x^n $ satisfies the differential equation:  $ (1 + x^2)f''(x) = 2f(x) $
>
> 1. Find $a_{2p + 1}$ in terms of $ p $, knowing that $ s(0) = 0 $ and $ s'(0) = 1 $,.
> 2. Let $ g (t) = \frac{s'(t) - 1}{t} $, with $ t \neq 0 $ and $g(0) = 0$.
>    Compute $ g'(t) $ and deduce an explicit expression of $ s $

---

For the first question, I found:

$$ a_{2p + 1} = \frac{\prod_{k = 0}^{p-1} [2k(2k + 1) - 2]}{(2p + 1)!}$$

For the second question, we have:

$$ g'(t) = \frac{ts''(t) - s'(t) + 1 }{t^2} $$

Using the power expansion of $s$ from the previous question, we get:

$$ g'(t) = \sum_{p = 1}^{+ \infty} (2p - 1) (2p + 1) a_{2p + 1} x^{2p - 2} $$

From here, I do not see how to proceed to get the expression of $g'(t)$ and the expression of $ s $.

Comment: Your $a_{2p+1}$ seems to be incorrect. If you factorise the term in the product, you can simplify the expression you got as $\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}[2k(2k+1)-2]}{(2p+1)!}=-\frac{2(p+1)}{(2p+1)}$, while the correct expression should be $a_{2p+1}=\frac1{(2p-1)(2p+1)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $s(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $s(0)=0,s'(0)=1$ implies that $a_0=0,a_1=1$.
Differentiating the series twice gives (noting that the first two terms disappear)
$$s''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2}$$
Therefore, since $0=(1+x^2)s''-2s$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
0&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n}-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n}-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\\
&=2a_2+6a_3x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\bigg((n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+n(n-1)a_{n}-2a_n\bigg)x^n-2a_0-2a_1x\\
&=\left(2a_2-2a_0\right)+\left(6a_3-2a_1\right)x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\bigg((n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+n(n-2)a_{n}-2a_n\bigg)x^n
\end{aligned}$$
Since this must hold for all $x$, the coefficients of $x^n$ must vanish individually. Therefore,
$$\begin{cases}
2a_2-2a_0=0\implies a_2=a_0=0\\6a_3-2a_1=0\implies a_3=a_1/3=1/3\\(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+\left(n(n-1)-2\right)a_n=0&n\ge2
\end{cases}$$
The last condition can be written as
$$(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}=-\left(n(n-1)-2\right)a_n=-(n^2-n-2)a_n=-(n+1)(n-2)a_n$$
Which implies that
$$a_{n+2}=-\frac{n-2}{n+2}a_{n}$$
for $n\ge2$. Since $a_2=0$, all even $a_n$ vanishes, while for odd $n=2p+1$,
$$\begin{aligned}
a_{2p+1}&=-\frac{(2p-1)-2}{(2p-1)+2}a_{2p-1}\\
&=\frac{(2p-1)-2}{(2p-1)+2}\cdot\frac{(2p-3)-2}{(2p-3)+2}a_{2p-3}\\
&=\ ...\\
&=(-1)^{p-1}\left(\prod_{k=2}^p\frac{(2k-1)-2}{(2k-1)+2}\right)a_3\\
&=(-1)^{p-1}\frac13\prod_{k=2}^p\frac{2k-3}{2k+1}\\
&=(-1)^{p-1}\frac13\cdot\frac{(1)(3)(5)...(2p-3)}{(5)...(2p-3)(2p-1)(2p+1)}\\
&=\boxed{\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{(2p-1)(2p+1)}}
\end{aligned}$$
Note that this derivation only works when $2p-1\ge2$, or $2p+1\ge4$. **Notably, the formula does not hold when $p=0$.** You can also skip this derivation by trying a few values, guessing the formula and proving it with induction.
For part 2, doing the required operations gives
$$\begin{aligned}
s(t)&=x+\sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{p-1}t^{2p+1}}{(2p-1)(2p+1)}\\
s'(t)&=1+\sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{p-1}t^{2p}}{2p-1}\\
g(t)&=\frac{s'(t)-1}{t}=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{p-1}t^{2p-1}}{2p-1}\\
g'(t)&=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{p-1}t^{2p-2}=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{p}t^{2p}
\end{aligned}$$
Using the geometric sum formula $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac1{1-x}$, we can write
$$\begin{aligned}
g'(t)&=\frac1{1+t^2}\\
g(t)&=\tan^{-1}t+C\\
s'(t)&=tg(t)+1=t\tan^{-1}t+Ct+1
\end{aligned}$$
We actually can't infer $C$ using the initial conditions $s(0)=0,s'(0)=1$. However, from the earlier fact that $a_2=0$, we can deduce that $s''(0)=0$, and if we differentiate our current expression for $s'(t)$:
$$s''(t)=\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\tan^{-1}t+C$$
we see that $C=0$. Thus, $s'(t)=t\tan^{-1}t+1$ and integrating gives
$$s(t)=\int_0^t\left(t'\tan^{-1}t'+1\right)\text{ d}t'=\frac12\left((t^2+1)\tan^{-1}t+t\right)$$

Comment: Ah! I see where I made the mistake. Thank you very much for your help.